# How to look up an object's property which is numerical?

Tags: python

I think I know how to deal with this if it were a dict, but it's now become a bit hard for me to separate hashes from objects because of *too much javascript*.

This terminal dump should demonstrate the problem that I have:

```
% python
Python 2.7.4 (default, Jul  3 2013, 17:42:47)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 3.4 (trunk 185360)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import argparse
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument('--256', '-256', action='store_true')
_StoreTrueAction(option_strings=['--256', '-256'], dest='256', nargs=0, const=True, default=False, type=None, choices=None,
 help=None, metavar=None)
>>> args = parser.parse_args()
>>> dir(args)
['256', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__h
ash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof_
_', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_get_args', '_get_kwargs']
>>> args.256
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    args.256
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Basically, `argparse` has worked great for me right up until I want to start to specify a flag `-256` that toggles the program's 256-color terminal support (that is, whether it emits 256 color ANSI codes or 8 color ANSI codes)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`getattr()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
getattr(args, '256')
```

but you may want to avoid this problem by setting a `dest` destination:

```
parser.add_argument('--256', '-256', action='store_true', dest='ff')
```

Comment: Isn't it `dest` that would have to be changed, not `metavar`?

Comment: +++ OUT OF CAFFEINE ERROR +++ REDO FROM START +++